# pygame.time.Clock.get_fps does not exist

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-clock

so I am trying to display my fps in game, but whenver I try to use the pygame.time.Clock.get_fps function,
it says it does not exict as an atribute

I tried:

`clock = pygame.time.Clock`
`print(clock.get_fps())`
`print(pygame.time.clock.get_fps())`
`print(pygame.time.Clock.get_fps())`

as you see, I am desperate

Comment: Did you try to read the docs?

Comment: You need to create an instance of the `Clock` class , e.g. `clock = pygame.time.Clock()`. From this instance you can get the fps with `clock.get_fps()`. See [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the parenthesis here,

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock #<=
```

it should be

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

that way you can get the methods of the `time.Clock()` class, ie `get_fps()`.